# TeamViewer VPN does not change public IP

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm confused about how TeamViewer's VPN service works. When I used a dedicated VPN program like CyberGhost before, it would change my public IP so that my traffic appeared to originate from a separate location. Now, I recently set up a separate computer on a different network that I planned to use TeamViewer's VPN to connect through and once again retain my anonymity, but this time with more control, speed, and less bandwidth limitations. To my surprise however, after connecting my current computer to the remote server I set up with TeamViewer, it did not change my public IP. In fact, I'm not even entirely sure it did much other than connect the LAN network of this pc and that one.

My question is this; is my anonymity preserved with this solution? Or do I need a different type of service? If so, where would I find the software necessary for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teamviewer's VPN is not meant to be built as a proxying service, what you are hoping for. Rather, it only establishes an IP that can be used to communicate with another machine on a separate network.

To answer your question, in order to setup something like you are hoping for, you would need something like OpenVPN or as a basic HTTP proxy, something like Squid, running on your home machine.

But, a thing to note is that most traditional ISPs have a higher download rate than upload rate. So, when working remotely, you would depend on your upload rate to get data through your VPN, thus it is likely you will not achieve the speed that you are expecting by setting this up.

Comment: Thank you for thew advice. I know that my ISP's upload is fairly slow compared it it's download, but I am prepared to deal with that. Besides, I still have the other advantages of a personal proxy server. Edit: Doesn't OpenVPN require you register for their account?